# Topology vs Borel sigma-algebra on a set $X$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

What is the difference between: ($X$: a set)

1. Topology (open set system) on $X$
2. Borel sigma-algebra on $X$

---

Both are a set of open subsets.
Both include $X$ and empty set.
Both are closed under union and intersection.

---

They look like the same thing, right?
Or  2. is the smallest sigma-algebra containing 1.?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They're not the same. If you have a topology (only the open sets) you get a Borel $\sigma$-algebra: the smallest one containing all open sets (so that contains the topology).

But this also contains all closed sets, all countable intersections of open sets (which need *not* be open, nor closed) etc. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra will generally be a lot bigger.

Also note that $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complements (!), *countable* unions and *countable* intersections. While topologies are closed under *finite* intersections and *arbitrary* unions. So quite different.

Any space with a topology automatically has a Borel $\sigma$-algebra (if we need it, say for measure theory), while the having a $\sigma$-algebra does not mean having a topology.

Comment: Nice...much more clear and detailed

Comment: @sleevechen Glad to be able to help

Answer (score 6):

A $\sigma$ algebra needs to be closed under ${\bf countable}$ union and under complementation. Now, a topology is closed under ${\bf any}$ union and in general not closed under complementation.

This holds in general. Furthermore, you have that the Borel $\sigma$ algebra contains the topology (by definition), hence it contains the closed sets too, so that in general those two objects are different.

Comment: +1 But I have a question that may sound like I'm picking on the grammar, but I'm not - I'm stuck at the word 'hence', which connotes that the preceding statement somewhat explains what follows. Would it be OK to say insted: "the Borel sigma algebra contains the topology, BUT it contains the closed sets too,..."? That is to say, two separate statements.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that as the $\sigma$ algebra contains the open sets, it contains the closed as well (by closure under complementation), so that in general it is different from the topology