# What is the meaning of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a toplogy

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Reading about random sets, I've come across the phrase
"$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology of closed convergence." where $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}.$

I don't know a lot about topology, so I'm not sure how to understand/interpret this. In general, a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a set $S$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $S$, and I suppose a topology gives a notion of "openness", but I would appreciate if someone could provide me some intuition behind this particular $\sigma$-algebra and the "topology of closed convergence".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929513/topology-vs-borel-sigma-algebra-on-a-set-x

Comment: See also [this note](https://www.math.kit.edu/iag4/lehre/stochgeom2010s/media/topology.pdf).

Comment: That isn't too helpful. I know the difference between a Borel sigma algebra and a topology. What I'm asking concerns the Borel sigma algebra generated by a particular topology

Comment: A topology = the family of all open sets (in that topology). So the sigma-algebra generated by a topology is the same as the sigma-algebra generated by open sets (in that topology). In general, *a topology* on a set $X$ is just a family of subsets of $X$ closed under arbitrary unions, finite intersections and containing $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

For any family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of a set $X$ we can talk about the $\sigma$-algebra *generated by* $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, which is the defined to be the intersection of **all** $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{F}$ as a subset. This is standard in measure theory. It's well-defined as the intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra again and we always have at least one $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{F}$, namely the power set of $X$.

A topology on $X$ is just another such family $\mathcal{F}$ so the definition applies. The $\sigma$-algebra will thus contain all open sets, all closed sets (their complements), all $G_\delta$ sets and $F_\sigma$ sets etc. (all in that topology). It's also called the *Borel* $\sigma$-algebra of a topological space.